# HAProxy path_beg not redirecting

Tags: haproxy

I'm testing a simple haproxy rule to make http://localhost/haproxy-dconv take me to http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv but it isn't working. 404 response seems to be from the site but the path isn't resolving.

```
frontend HTTP
  mode http
  bind *:80

  acl url_dconv path_beg /haproxy-dconv
  use_backend dconv-backend if url_dconv

backend dconv-backend
  mode http
  server dconv cbonte.github.io
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this -

```
frontend HTTP
    mode http
    bind *:80
    use_backend dconv-backend if { path_beg /haproxy-dconv/ }

backend dconv-backend
    mode http
    server dconv cbonte.github.io
```

Source: https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.7/configuration.html#use_backend

Answer (score 1):

That is because the Host header that is being sent is localhost, instead of cbonte.github.io. Add this to your backend:

```
http-request set-header Host cbonte.github.io
```

Also note that without the ending slash, you will get a 301, so make sure you send http://localhost/cbonte-dconv/ and fix your ACL.

Answer (score 0):

You are using Haproxy in an incorrect way.

You need to match the ACL to get the URL between host and query parameter as you do:

```
acl url_dconv path_beg /haproxy-dconv
```

Then using this ACL to redirect from localhost if ACL is matched:

```
redirect prefix http://cbonte.github.io code 301 if url_dconv
```

But again this is more a conceptual problem of thinking redirect and matching path.