# HAProxy - Unable to redirect requests with similar URL with path ACL

Tags: routes, acl, haproxy

I'm not able to correctly redirect requests of API calls that are very similar in URL.

My configuration is the following (some parts redacted):

frontend:

```
frontend https
  bind :443 ssl crt /opt/haproxy/cert
  capture request header X-TRACE len 32
  log-format %ci:%cp\[%t]\ %ft\ %b/%s\ %Tq/%Tw/%Tc/%Tr/%Tt\ %ST\ %B\ %CC\ %CS\ %tsc\ %ac/%fc/%bc/%sc/%rc\ %sq/%bq\ %hr\ %hs\ %{+Q}r

  reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ https

  use_backend foo if { path -m beg /foo }
  use_backend foo-v2 if { path_sub /foo-v2 }
```

backend:

```
backend foo
  option httpchk GET /foo/healthcheck HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:\ www\r\nAuthorization:\ Basic\ ...
  http-check expect rstatus 200
  server bar1 xx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx check inter 10s maxconn 2000

backend foo-v2
  option httpchk GET /foo-v2/healthcheck HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:\ www\r\nAuthorization:\ Basic\ ...
  http-check expect rstatus 200
  server bar1 xx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx check inter 10s maxconn 2000
  server bar2 xx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx check inter 10s maxconn 2000
```

As you can see, the only thing that separates the requests from each other is the `-v2` addition to the v2 requests. However all requests (regardless if with v2 or not) get sent through the first backend instead of matching with the v2 backend when v2 requests are made.

Comment: Before anyone asks, I have looked around in the documentation and similar threads, but can't seem to solve this issue;  docs:
https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.8/configuration.html#7.3.6-path
https://www.haproxy.com/documentation/aloha/10-0/traffic-management/lb-layer7/acls/#matching-strings ;

threads:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43081363/haproxy-path-beg-not-redirecting
https://serverfault.com/questions/306968/how-can-i-make-haproxy-route-requests-based-on-url-substrings

Comment: I think you need a terminator on your foo path. It's just looking at any that begin `/foo` which includes `/foo-v2`. Perhaps `path_reg ^/foo$`?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I tried this suggestion but it doesn't seem to work in my case. Even escaping the forwardslash with a backslash. I'm not sure why `foo-v2` requests are being directed to the `foo` backend.